# JavaScript click event on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I am working on JavaScript project and I am having a problem with click event and retrieving the correct information about the element clicked. I am relatively new to the JavaScript.

The real code I am working on is fairly complex however I am posting only a chunk of code to illustrate my problem.

```js
function App(){
this.name = "New App";
}

App.prototype.createDIV = function() {

  var h = "<div class='clickable' id='idToShow'><div class='name' id='notToShow'>" + this.name + "</div></div>";

  $('#content').html(h);
}

App.prototype.showID = function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'idToShow') {
    alert(this.name);  // this doesn't display, because incorrect ID is retrieved
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var newApp = new App();

  $("input#btn").click(newApp.createDIV.bind(newApp));
  $("div").on("click", ".clickable", newApp.showID.bind(newApp));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="CLICK">
```

I have a object in the app with number of prototypes. On document load, object is constructed, events are attached to elements and bind to object. Clicking the button, new set of div results are created dynamically.

Now this is where it starts to go wrong for me. I attached an event to div with the class CLICKABLE and I would like to retrieve the id of that particular DIV element (id='idToShow'); however I keep retrieving the id of the following DIV (id='notToShow').

I might not fully understand why is this happening and what to do to prevent it in order to get the correct ID.

Comment: If createDIV can execute multiple times, which it looks like it can because it is an event handler, you can't use your ids like you are.  Ids must be unique on a page.  They are *unique* identifiers.  Side note, you have a <dic> element.  Typo?

Comment: You're missing `{` after `function App()`

Comment: Thank you for noting the <dic> and missing {, it was my typo. Those ID's are actually unique in the app (they are ID's of items returned in JSON), I just used these to illustrate the issue I had. The answer bellow seems to work for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `if (e.currentTarget.id == 'idToShow')` instead of `if (e.target.id == 'idToShow')`.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly for me! Why is it when using "e.target.id" returns the id of the last child within the nested div?